# как оставить в одном из полей dataframe только числовые значения больше нуля?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df[df[cols] > 0]
```

выдает ошибку

> '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `cols` - это наименование столбца или список столбцов?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: cols - столбец, в котором вперемешку и числа и текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйта так:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df[cols], errors='coerce') > 0]
```

Пример:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   id            col
0   1             12
1   2  blah-blah_123
2   3              0
3   4              7

In [26]: df[pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce') > 0]
Out[26]:
   id col
0   1  12
3   4   7
```

Comment: да. все сработало. Спасибо!